# How to group a taxonomy by groups

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I’m working on a page where I use a custom post type with 2 custom taxonomy. My custom post type is called “series” and my custom taxonomies are called “temporada” & "capitulo".

I want to list all the temporadas but group them together with their respective capitulos.

So to be clear, I’ve 2 Temporadas. (temporada 1) have (7 capitulos)
and (temporada 2) have (11 capitulos)

I want to group all the capitulos with their respective temporadas.

Im using this code:

```
<?php

$temporada = 'temporada';
$capitulo = 'capitulo';
$tax_temporada = get_terms($temporada);
$tax_capitulos = get_terms($capitulo);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($tax_temporada); $i++) {
echo '<div class="panel panel-default">';
echo '<div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="c'. $tax_capitulos[$i]->name.'">';
echo '<h4 class="panel-title">' . '<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#'. $tax_temporada[$i]->name.'" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="' . $tax_temporada[$i]->name.'" >Temporada: ' . $tax_temporada[$i]->name.'</a></h4>';
echo '</div>';
echo '<div id="'. $tax_temporada[$i]->name.'" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="c'. $tax_capitulos[$i]->name.'">';
echo '<div class="panel-body">';

foreach ($tax_capitulos as $tax_capitulo) {
echo '<li>' . '<a href="' . esc_attr(get_term_link($tax_capitulo,   $taxonomy)) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $tax_capitulo->name ) . '" ' . '>Capitulo: ' . $tax_capitulo->name.'</a></li>';
}
echo '</div>'.'</div>'.'</div>';

}
?>
```

The code Show me this: (all the capitulos are the same....)

- -Temporada 1

  --capitulo 1

  --capitulo 2

  --capitulo 3
- -Temporada 2

  --capitulo 1

  --capitulo 2

  --capitulo 3

This is the code to show each capitulo

```
foreach ($tax_capitulos as $tax_capitulo) {
echo '<li>' . '<a href="' . esc_attr(get_term_link($tax_capitulo, $taxonomy)) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $tax_capitulo->name ) . '" ' . '>Capitulo: ' . $tax_capitulo->name.'</a></li>';
}
```

But, Is like I need a Filter to show Just the capitulos with the respective temporada

With this one is how I Add the custom taxonomy

```
register_taxonomy(
'temporada', 
array('series' ),
array('hierarchical' => false,
        // This array of options controls the labels displayed in the WordPress Admin UI
        'labels' => array(
          'name' => _x( 'Temporada', 'taxonomy general name' ),
          'singular_name' => _x( 'Temporada', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
          'search_items' =>  __( 'Buscar Temporadas' ),
          'all_items' => __( 'TodosTemporada las Temporadas' ),
          'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Temporadas' ),
          'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Temporadas:' ),
          'edit_item' => __( 'Editar Temporadas' ),
          'update_item' => __( 'Actualizar Temporadas' ),
          'add_new_item' => __( 'Agregar Nueva Temporadas' ),
          'new_item_name' => __( 'Nuevo Temporadas Nombre' ),
          'menu_name' => __( 'Temporada' ),
          'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Temporada del capitulo, Ej: 1, 2', 'cc' ),
    'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Buscar entre los mas Usados', 'cc' ),
        ),
// Control the slugs used for this taxonomy
'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_admin_column'     => true,
    'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
    'query_var'             => true,
    'rewrite'               => false,


));
register_taxonomy(
'capitulo', 
array('series' ),
array('hierarchical' => false,
        // This array of options controls the labels displayed in the WordPress Admin UI
        'labels' => array(
          'name' => _x( 'Capitulo', 'taxonomy general name' ),
          'singular_name' => _x( 'capitulo', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
          'search_items' =>  __( 'Buscar capitulo' ),
          'all_items' => __( 'Todos las capitulo' ),
          'parent_item' => __( 'Parent capitulo' ),
          'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent capitulo:' ),
          'edit_item' => __( 'Editar capitulo' ),
          'update_item' => __( 'Actualizar capitulo' ),
          'add_new_item' => __( 'Agregar Nueva capitulo' ),
          'new_item_name' => __( 'Nuevo Nombre Capitulo' ),
          'menu_name' => __( 'Capitulo' ),
          'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Capitulo, Ej: 1, 2', 'cc' ),
    'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Buscar entre los mas Usados', 'cc' ),
        ),
// Control the slugs used for this taxonomy
'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_admin_column'     => true,
    'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
    'query_var'             => true,
   'rewrite'               => false,


));

}
add_action( 'init', 'serie_custom_taxonomies', 0 );
```

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while but I can see your problem.

Your inner loop which is a nice friendly `foreach` (I prefer `foreach` to `for`) but it is looping all of the `$tax_capitulos` because you have not told it how to find only the `$tax_capitulos` that relate to the `$tax_temporada`.

The way you describe the system `$tax_capitulos` group by or belong to `$tax_temporada` but your code does not reflect this. I do not know the system well enough to know the object relationship but I would expect to see something of the kin of:

```
foreach ($tax_temporada->tax_capitulos as $tax_capitulo) {
    // etc
}
```

or

```
foreach ($tax_capitulos[$tax_temporada[$i]] as $tax_capitulo) {
    // etc
}
```

or

```
foreach (get_tax_capitulos($tax_temporada[$i]) as $tax_capitulo) {
    // etc
}
```

or something that defines a relationship. I have my doubts that this is how your data format works but I hope you understand what I am getting at here.

As it stands you will get all of the `$tax_capitulos` listed under each `$tax_temporada` because this is what you code is telling it to do.

I hope this in some way helps you. That's about as far as I can go towards answering your question without having greater knowledge of your wider code base.

Comment: Im Using 2 custom taxonomy, 1 temporada(season) and 1 capitulo (chapter). My Problem is the one that you describe "your code does not reflect this." I try in some diferents ways, but getting errors.

Comment: I add more the code that i use to show the taxonomy i hope that help.